# Magento htaccess regex not working

Tags: regex, .htaccess, magento

I am trying to create a regex pattern in magento htaccess to link category based on keyword "guest" or "guests"

Below is the rule I have tried in htaccess file

```
RewriteRule /\bgues(?:t|ts)\b/ www.domain.com/categorypath [L]

RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
```

The above rewrite rule is not working.

Please help me sorting this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution

we should put the first "RewriteRule" just below the "RewriteEngine on" in the htaccess file. Then it will work :)

Keep the below line as it is

```
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
```

The working RewriteRule and I hope this will be helpful for some one

```
RewriteRule \bgues(?:t|ts)\b /contactus/index/seo [R]
```

Below Rule is not working

```
RewriteRule \bgues(?:t|ts)\b /contactus/index/seo [L]
```

Actually I want internal redirect and not external redirect if some one knows please post here.

Answer (score 0):

It would be the 'Magento way' to use Magento's built-in catalog URL rewrites to control this behaviour. Maybe you have a reason not to, but in the `Magento Admin->Catalog->URL rewrite management`, click on `Add URL Rewrite` (top right).

You would want a 'For category' `type`: just click on the category from the list. Now on the rewrite page enter 'guests' as the request path. While you are here write down the `'Target path'` (it should be something like `catalog/category/view/id/251` and you will use it next). Save your new rewrite and test that `/guests` displays the page at `/categorypath`.

Now for `/guest` - it is a little different (because Magento likes the `'ID Path'` to be unique). This time select `'Custom'` from the `'Create URL Rewrite:'` drop down. There are more boxes to fill in but just put `ID path = guests` (the URL you created above), Request path = guest and set Target path the same target path for the category eg `catalog/category/view/id/251`.

You can continue in this way to instruct Magento to make many URLs go to the same target path by chaining the ID paths and Request paths.

Changing the `Magento .htaccess` is difficult because Magento does not route URLs using htaccess. If you need advanced routing I would suggest you extend to Magento's front-end routers which you can learn about from Alan Storm's excellent website articles. Otherwise, stick to the built in catalog URL rewrites.

Note that, later, if you drop the `core_url_rewrite table` from your `Magento database` and reindex it (because a big rewrite table might be slowing down your website), you may loose these manual entries and have to re-enter them; so add that to your *Magento Periodic Maintenance Checklist* (or write a script to recreate the table entries in core_url_rewrite).

Comment: Thanks for your valuable comments. Imagine we have 1000 category and for that we need to create a seo URL with a keyword(guest,shop etc..). In Magento way we have to add 1000 URL for this however this is not a right way to do it, if we create a regex in htaccess we can achieve the same in one single line.Now tell me which one is better